# SelectedList Item Id returning default value

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

```
@model List<Department>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-4 pb-4">
         <div class=" col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">
                Department List
            </h2>
         </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-end">
            <a asp-controller="Department" asp-action="CreateDept" class="btn btn-primary">
                Create
            </a>
            
 <a asp-controller="Question" asp-action="CreateQuestion" class="btn btn-primary mx-4">
                Create Questions
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
    

  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
             Department Name
            </th>
            
             
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var obj in Model)
        {
            <tr>
            <td>@obj.DepartmentalName</td>

                   
            </tr> 
        }
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```
@model QuestionView

<div class="container">
    <h2>Create Question</h2>
    <form method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Question.DepartmentId" />


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Question.Text">Question Text:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Question.Text"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="Question.OptionA" class="p-0"></label>
            <input type="radio" asp-for="Question.IsCorrect" value="OptionA" name="correctOption" />
            <input asp-for="Question.OptionA" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Question.OptionA" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="Question.OptionB" class="p-0"></label>
            <input type="radio" asp-for="Question.IsCorrect" value="OptionB" name="correctOption" />
            <input asp-for="Question.OptionB" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Question.OptionB" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="Question.OptionC" class="p-0"></label>
            <input type="radio" asp-for="Question.IsCorrect" value="OptionC" name="correctOption" />
            <input asp-for="Question.OptionC" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Question.OptionC" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="Question.OptionD" class="p-0"></label>
            <input type="radio" asp-for="Question.IsCorrect" value="OptionD" name="correctOption" />
            <input asp-for="Question.OptionD" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Question.OptionD" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        

        <div class=" mb-3 row p-1">
            <select asp-for="@Model.Question.DepartmentId" asp-items="@Model.DepartmentList" class=" form-select p-0">
                <option disabled selected>-Selected Department-</option>
            </select>

            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Question.DepartmentId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Create Question</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
//Action methods from controller
public IActionResult CreateQuestion()
{
    var departmentsList = _unitOfWork.Department.GetAll().Select(u => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.DepartmentalName,
        Value = u.DepartmentId.ToString()
    });
    QuestionView vm = new()
    {
        DepartmentList = departmentsList,
        Question = new Question()
    };
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateQuestion(QuestionView obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Question.AddAObj(obj.Question);
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(obj);
}
```

Whenever I tried to create questions for a particular department , I am not getting the Id of the Department selected from SelectedListItem element what I am getting is the default value of 0 irrespective of the department selected from the SelectedListItem.

The question object being created should carry a DepartmentId, showing the uniqueness of a question to a department.

//QuestionView

```
public class QuestionView
{
    public Question? Question { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? DepartmentList { get; set; }
}
//corresponding model
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string OptionA { get; set; }
    public string OptionB { get; set; }
    public string OptionC { get; set; }
    public string OptionD { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department? Department { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Do you specifically mean that in your `CreateQuestion` method the `obj` parameter has an incorrect `SelectedDepartmentId` property value?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the Network tab, when the request is made, what keys/values are sent to the server?  What is the model structure for `QuestionView`?

Comment: public class QuestionView
    {
        public Question? Question { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem>? DepartmentList { get; set; }
    }


@David Thanks for the response.  
The DepartmentId is always Zero(Default value) irrespective of the department I am navigating from.

Comment: You've changed the code in the question.  Have you re-tested since making that change?  Has the behavior changed at all?  Have you checked the request being sent to the server yet?

Comment: Yes I did, it shoudn't be there. I forgot to remove it when posting. for the request I am getting a 200 response. The behaviour is still the same.

Comment: You're conveniently not addressing the debugging step of checking the body of the request being made to the server.  Why?  If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to start.

Comment: @David , this is what I am getting https://localhost:7032/Question/CreateQuestion/2 as my request initiator after clicking in a bid to create question for  the second department created , is this correct?

Comment: It looks like the correct URL.  What about the body of the POST request?  What does it contain?  (In the Network tab of the browser's debugging tools you may need to enable an option to preserve history, as a page navigation event may by default clear that tool's history.)

Comment: Question.DepartmentId: 0
Question.Text: gghj
correctOption: OptionA
Question.OptionA: fff
Question.OptionB: ffff
Question.OptionC: uuifder
Question.OptionD: 
SelectedDepartmentId: 2
__RequestVerificationToken: CfDJ8NXq3xqyA3FHpV5uNZf13xhQUu5vmyYn-6TAyRAtCt32Uqs58P3yxECLkJQWCF87WG1hzGy2hkNuG6tdaD8EfI01QaSHA8VWiRimmeQ6-Jbi3v5WzsBWCH8GWk7xlMRzHGgPrB-Tj_HqpJl6PX_-vLE

The above is what I got when from my post in trying to create a question for department with id number 2.

Comment: That data includes a `DepartmentId` *and* still has a `SelectedDepartmentId`, which was the `name` attribute used in the original code that you've since changed.  The former is likely coming from `<input type="hidden" asp-for="Question.DepartmentId" />`, why is that element there in the first place?  If that has a value of `0` in the resulting HTML then that would be why a `0` is being posted for that form element.  The latter on the other hand appears to be from the code that you removed from the question but are in some way still using when you test.

Comment: Thanks David. I included this line <input type="hidden" asp-for="Question.DepartmentId" /> when I was looking for solution to my problem, though I tried commenting it out when I was testing it but it still didn't work then. Now it is working,

Answer (score 0):

This form field:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Question.DepartmentId" />
```

And this form field:

```
<select asp-for="@Model.Question.DepartmentId" asp-items="@Model.DepartmentList" class=" form-select p-0">
  <option disabled selected>-Selected Department-</option>
</select>
```

Are for the same model property.  Why do you need both?  The property can only have one value.

If no value is being used to *populate* the view, then `DepartmentId` will have the default value for an `int`, which is `0`.  You can check the client-side source in your browser to confirm, but that would mean the hidden input has a value of `0`.

[In a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022490/selectedlist-item-id-returning-default-value#comment135783779_77022490) you indicated that the data posted to the server includes this:

```
SelectedDepartmentId: 2
```

There is no such form element in the code shown.  But there [*was*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77022490/1) before you changed the code in the question.  The described result indicates that you haven't made that same change (or have made other changes) to the code you're actually using.

Your models have no property called `SelectedDepartmentId`, so it's not clear why you want a form field with that `name`.

If you want that form field to map to `Question.DepartmentId` then remove the explicit `name` attribute from it and let the `asp-for` framework attribute assign the correct `name` to the form element.  Additionally, remove the hidden input if you're not using it, since it's posting data to the server that you don't want.

Comment: Oh I am just seeing your comment now, I did exactly as you said above before seeing your comment and it's working now. 
Thanks for the time and the efforts.